# Transactions in "dapper-dot-net"

Tags: architecture, data-access-layer, dapper

How do I create a transaction if my DAL is using dapper-dot-net?

My c# winform application will be used in network and the data will be saved to a central sql server.

My use case requires use of transactions. Can I do this using dapper, or will I need to use something like NHibernate?

Also, is there any risk or limitation with this framework if I am using stored procedures? Will I need to change my approach due any possible limitations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't run into any limitations with using sprocs and the risks you have with dapper are the same risks you would have with sprocs

Here is a simple example on how to use transactions with dapper

```
using (var connection = Db.GetConnection())
{
     connection.Open();
     IDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
     try
     {
         var newId= connection.Query<int>(@"Select id from table1 where id=@id", new{id}, transaction).Single();
         connection.Execute(@"INSERT into table1 ...",new {p1, p2}, transaction);
         connection.Execute(@"INSERT into table2 ...",new {p1, p2}, transaction);
         transaction.Commit();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         transaction.Rollback();
     }
}
```

Comment: :) I see I forgot to declare the transaction as IDbTransaction.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Also, I hope, there will not be any limitation or issue while using stored procedure.  Actually, i am new with drapper so, i asked it.

Comment: @DPSoni it will behave identically to any other ADO.NET usage

Answer (score 3):

dapper can use both ado.net transactions and implicit transactions. For ado.net transactions, just create the transaction normally and provide it via the `transaction` parameter that is available on the main methods. For implicit transactions, just use `TransactionScope` normally.