# How to determine if IDbConnection supports transactions?

Tags: c#, .net, database, database-connection, compatibility

I'm trying to keep my class library as compatible with as many database systems as possible utilizing generics of type `IDbConnection`, `IDbCommand`, and `IDbDataParameter`, but supporting transactions with `IDbTransaction` when possible is definitely preferable.  Some implementations of `IDbConnection`, however, will not support transactions (MySQL/ MyISAM comes to mind).

How can I determine whether or not a concrete implementation of `IDbConnection` supports transactions?

To be clear, I want to support database backends that do not support transactions, but default to transactions if they can be used.

Comment: If you require a transaction, couldn't your method signature simply require an `IDbTransaction` over `IDbConnection`? `IDbTransaction` still exposes the original `IDbConnection`.  Why do you need to know this information?  You could provide an overload of your, say, `Execute` method that does something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14102615/251983 - then the user can choose Connection or Transaction.

Comment: Will this work for `IDbConnection` implementations to databases that do not support transactions?  I would expect a `NotSupportedException` in that case.

Comment: That becomes the responsibility of the caller.  If your taansactionalized methods are simply an overload, then the caller wouldn't use them on an implementation that doesn't support transactions. IMO you can't make this decision for the consumer of your library bc you don't know how they'll use it.
FYI it looks like MySQL has a transaction implementation http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlTransaction.html but full disclosure, I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't if you only have an `IDbConnection`. You should assume that the implementation support transactions and write your library accordingly.

Comment: Why should I assume anything?  That seems like bad design right from the get-go.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs you should be able to assume this since if someone gives you access to their concrete implementation, unless they are having a laugh, it will be completed and tested for you to consume. This allows you to use IDbConnection as a variable type that can swap between holding you're custom connection type or other implementations allowing you to use different connections with the exact same code.